# Usage of Spock Mocks in the same way that was done with Mockito

Tags: java, groovy, mocking, mockito, spock

I just have an Object that I mock with Mockito, and I need to do the equivalent with Spock.
How do you guys recommend to do it?

This is the way that I did with Mockito

```
        XptoOutputBoundary xpto;
        doAnswer({ invocation ->
            xpto = invocation.getArgumentAt(1, OutputBoundary.class)
            xpto.response.response.abcd01 = abcd01
            xpto.response.response.abcd02 = abcd02
            xpto.response.response.abcd03 = abcd03
            xpto.response.response.abcd04 = null
            xpto.response.response.abcd05 = null
            xpto.response.response.abcd06 = abcd06
            xpto.response.response.abcd07 = abcd07
            return null
        }).when(service).execute(any(), any())
```

How can I mock in the same way, but using Spock?

**UPDATE**

Hello!

I've tried one of the suggestions, but it still not work... the "xpto" object keeps getting null using spock

Here is how is the code now:

```
        given: 'i have a valid object'
        AbcdObjectXptoResponse xptoResponse = Fixture.from(AbcdObjectXptoResponse.class).gimme("valid")
        AbcdObjectRequest request = Fixture.from(AbcdObjectRequest.class).gimme("valid")
        XptoOutputBoundary xpto;

        repository.execute(_ as XptoOutputBoundary, _) >> { args ->
            xpto = args[0] 
            xpto.response.response.abcd01 = abcd01
            xpto.response.response.abcd02 = abcd02
            xpto.response.response.abcd03 = abcd03
            xpto.response.response.abcd04 = null
            xpto.response.response.abcd05 = null
            xpto.response.response.abcd06 = abcd06
            xpto.response.response.abcd07 = abcd07
        }


        when: 'the request is performed'
        def response = service.getAbcdObjectRequest(request)
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: It appears that what you're doing is accepting an argument of type `OutputBoundary` and mutating it; is that correct?

Comment: Please update the question, providing a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just a code snippet out of context. Show full classes with imports and package names, all of class under test, dependency classes and test class. No problem if you rename all classes and packages and remove everything not needed to reproduce your situation, but as it stands now you will just waste your own time and chrylis' time too, discussing in multiple iterations. I mean to guide to how to ask better questions more than criticise you, I hope you understand. 

Comment: @kriegaex The full import list, etc., is not really necessary for the question as posed here.

Comment: Good for you if you do not need it. However, it would certainly be helpful and speed things up because you would not have discuss iteratively with the OP in comments and your answer would be accepted by now. It would also help me and others to just reproduce the situation and fix it within a minute without any speculations. You used the word "assumption" in your own answer.

Comment: You _still_ haven't shown the interface being mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code appears to be very Java-flavored Groovy using Mockito, returning `null` for some particular reason (instead of simply being void). Operating on that assumption, then the Spock equivalent would be something like this:

```
MyService service = Mock()

def 'test case'() {
  when:
  'things happen'

  then:
  // you really should put constraints on your arguments, not just any() or _
  service.execute(_ as XptoOutputBoundary, _) >> { args ->
      XptoOutputBoundary xpto = args[0] // or 1?
      // do the same things
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much for your answer.
I've just tried to replicate this in my test, however it did not work. Apparently it does not generate the object, so I'm not able to advance to the when actions...
this is how my test is now

```
given: 'a valid request'
 service.execute(XptoOutputBoundary, _) >> { args ->
  xpto = args[0]
xpto.response.response.abcd02 = abcd02
xpto.response.response.abcd04 = null
...

when: 'perform the request'
  otherService.getTheObjectThatIWant()
...
}

```

Do you know what am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: @Rodrigo I said `_ as XptoOutputBoundary`, not `XptoOutputBoundary`; read the Spock docs on writing interactions. What you wrote was "when `XptoOutputBoundary.class` is passed as the first parameter", which is not what I think you want.

Comment: Thanks @Chriylis!
Actually was my mistake.
I adjust it to the same way now, and it is throwing the InvokerInvocationException...
I think its because I'm calling the execute() method before populating de xpto.response object

Comment: @Rodrigo The closure isn't invoked until the `execute` method is called, and the interaction should _usually_ go in the `then:` block.

Comment: @Rodrigo it would help if you could update your question with your current specification code and the new error you get. Reading larger code in the comments is not really nice.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic I have updated the question to make it easier to understand how is the code now.
I still was not able to make it work.